# How can I use a column data as values to create more headers

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if my question sounds confusing, I can't find a way to word this better.
I have this code here to calculate the pivot table

```
price_pivot_data = pd.pivot_table(out_data, values=["Price"], index=['Date', 'Payment method'])
```

And here's my current pivot table:

```
0                          Price
Date       Payment method       
2022-05-23 Void              0.0
2022-05-25 Credit            8.0
           Validation        8.0
2022-05-28 Credit            8.0
```

What I want is to use the Payment method column as headers for multiple column. So something like this:

```
Date        Void   Credit  Validation  Some other payment type 
2022-05-23  0.0    0.0     0.0         0.0
2022-05-25  0.0    8.0     8.0         0.0
2022-05-28  0.0    8.0     0.0         0.0
```

Regarding the other payment type column, NaN is fine. For the other payment type part, I can just manually add the column after so it's not required.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `unstack` then flatten the multi index column

```py
df = price_pivot_data.unstack().fillna(0)
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

```
print(df)

Payment method  Credit  Validation  Void
Date
2022-05-23         0.0         0.0   0.0
2022-05-25         8.0         8.0   0.0
2022-05-28         8.0         0.0   0.0
```